# Getting Started with Google Programming

Tags: gmail

I'm just beginning a project that involves working with a few of Google's APIs (for .NET), specifically the Contacts List, Calendar and Gmail.  While Google does provide a wealth of information through their code.google.com network, finding what I need to get started has thus far proven to be a monumental task.  What I'm hoping to find is a "big picture" look at what Google makes available to developers as well as a few sample pieces of code to ease me off the starting block.

Does anyone know where I can find a handful of simple, useful examples developing basic applications with Google's API (I've come across a few examples within code.google.com, but they're so rudimentary that they're not helpful)?  Are there any resources (in print or online) that can spoon feed a Google novice without burying them?  Is there a special, hidden nook within code.google.com for Google beginners?

Any information anyone could share would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/